# Why does pcolor output a mirrored array in this example?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

```
array = np.eye(5)
plt.pcolor(array)
```

If you were to do this code, the output graph would actually be a mirror of the defined array. why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just draws from the bottom left, which make quite sense if you check out the labeling on the x&y-axes. Check out [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html)
You can invert it though:

1. by flipping the y-axis

   `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()`
2. or by changing your input matrix (if appropriate ...)

   `plt.pcolor(np.eye(5)[::-1,:])`